# php curl select box values

Tags: php, regex, curl

I'm trying to get the values (preg_match) of an select list from one website.

HTML on website:

```
<select name="country_id" id="country_id">
    <option value="vi">Vietnam</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">France</option>
</select>
```

I have tryed with the next code but with no sucess:

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();

    $url = "<url_of_website>"; 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    preg_match_all('/<select name="country_id" id="country_id">(.*)<\/select>/msu', $result, $matches);
    print_r($matches);

    curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

I want to get the results like: vi, en, fr

Can anyone please help me?

Thank You.

Comment: How many times do people ask for regex matches on HTML?  Why not simply use DOM to read the HTML and get the values??

Comment: It would be better to use the DOMDocument to parse the returned response rather than regex

Comment: Checkout for similar posts: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HTML+parsing+using+DOMDocument

Comment: But I need to connect to another website, the page is not mine.
Sorry for any inconvenience...

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the DOM for what you want would look like this

Assuming this HTML is in the page you are requesting

```
<select name="country_id" id="country_id">
    <option value="vi">Vietnam</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">France</option>
</select>
```

This PHP will find the values of the `option` elements

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('<url_of_website>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$options = $xpath->query('*/select[@id="country_id"]/option');

$values = array();
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $values[] = $option->getAttribute('value');
}

print_r($values);
```

*Edited to show how to parse the DOM from a URL rather than some HTML in a variable*

Comment: Thank You for your reply but I need to connect to another website, the page is not mine. Sorry for any inconvenience...

Comment: This was basically to replace your `preg_match` code and show you how to parse any HTML with the DOMDocument.  As Casimir said in comments to the other answer, all you need to do is change `loadHTML($html)` to `loadHTMLFile($url)` and you wouldn't even need to us `cURL` anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOMDocument:

```
$html = <<<LOD
<select name="country_id" id="country_id">
    <option value="vi">Vietnam</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">France</option>
</select>
LOD;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$optionNodes = $doc->getElementById('country_id')->getElementsByTagName('option');
foreach($optionNodes as $optionNode) {
    echo $optionNode->getAttribute('value') . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply but I need to connect to another website, the page is not mine. Sorry for any inconvenience...

Comment: @ptCoder: in this case, just replace `loadHTML($html);` by `loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.com/page.html');`